# Some strange errors in XCode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have one project. It was working fine yesterday. But when i opened it today and compiled it it is throwing some strange errors. Don't know why?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to restart Xcode? Have you tried to restart your computer? Have you repaired the permissions? Have you reset the PRAM?

Comment: This looks like one of those errors where you by mistake deleted "@end" in header file or missing some "}" or "{". This is usually in corresponding header file or one of the included headers... See what file includes "DownloadManager" and then check its header...

Comment: @dasdom This seems like problem in Xcode. It is resolved. I have just created new file with same name and copy pasted code of old file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Bug in Xcode... on *WWDC* a Dev showed me a dirty workaround (is Fixed in Xcode 6 Beta):

1. Copy the File
2. Delete the Original File
3. Rename the Copied File to the Original
4. Clear & Rebuild

You can also delete the Project out from Xcode and readd it - will have the same effect - but copying and rename is a way faster.

I hope it is the same bug and helped.